Cypress API test, expect two possible response
In 'before' hook I have a bunch of API requests setting up my test user for tests, one of method is responsible for setting up a password and it can have to possible out comes:

204 if the user do not have any password yet, so it creating a new one
400 if the user already have the password

I would like test not to fail in both cases, is it possible to add 2 possible outcomes to response?
I have tried something like this but it doesn’t work, second value in eq() is completely ignored
cy.request({
method: 'PUT',
url: "url/endpoint"
headers: {
  Authorization: "Bearer " + Cypress.env("access_token_val"),
  Connection: "keep-alive",
  Host: "host",
},
body: {
  "type": "password",
  "value": password,
  "temporary": false
}
}).then((response) => {
  expect(response.status).to.eq(204||400) })

EDIT: Actually it fails even if I only have
expect(response.status).to.eq(400) 

I have also tried to use this, same results
expect(response.body).to.have.property("error") 

Is there any way to make the test pass with the 400 response? That's the whole response, the scenario is to use the same password on each environment rebuild.
Status: 400 - Bad Request
Headers: {
"x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
"strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
"x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
"content-type": "application/json",
"referrer-policy": "no-referrer",
"content-length": "128",
"date": "Fri, 26 Apr 2024 18:12:43 GMT"
}
Body: {
"error": "invalidPasswordHistoryMessage",
"error_description": "Invalid password: must not be equal to any of last 24 passwords."
}


Please read the tag descriptions before you use tags and don't spam tags. The API tag contains: "DO NOT USE". Your question is unrelated to TypeScript.

You want to add the failOnStatusCode option, for example using a public API for demo
cy.request({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',   // exists
  failOnStatusCode: false
})
.then(response => {
  expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
})

cy.request({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1000', // does not exist
  failOnStatusCode: false
})
.then(response => {
  expect(response.status).to.eq(404)
})



With that flag set to false you could use the oneOf assertion
  expect(response.status).to.be.oneOf([200, 404])


Your code doesn't work because 204||400 returns 204.


console.log(204||400);



expect(response.status).to.eq(204||400) is the same as expect(response.status).to.eq(204).
You can manually check the expected result
expect(response.status === 204 || response.status === 400).to.be.true


I have tried this solution but unfortunately test still fails 'The response we received from your web server was: > 400: Bad Request'

you can create a temporary flag that determines if the expect should pass and have a simple conditional check in your callback where you can check if either of your conditions are met and then flip the flag to pass or fail your test.
.then((response) => {
   let shouldPass = false;
   if(response.status === 204 || response.status === 400) {
      shouldPass = true
   }
   expect(shouldPass).to.be.true;


Still doesn’t work. Now I have tried to only have expect(response.status).to.eq(400) in then() - it fails.
Body: {
"error": "invalidPasswordHistoryMessage",
"error_description": "Invalid password: must not be equal to any of last 24 passwords."
}
I also tried to expect(response.body).to.have.property("error") but it also not working.
